# PHPExcel PDF Writer not working

Tags: php, phpexcel

[image]After ran the below code, i dont see any PDF Downloading as well in Browser PDF output not printed. Displaying blank page.

```
    require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('c9','40');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
//You need to include and print to PDF the entire worksheets contained in the workbook
$objWriter->writeAllSheets();

//You need to assign a filename to the PDF file (write.pdf for example)
header('Content-type:Application/pdf'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="export.pdf"');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Still there is a small mistake on the code. unable to download while viewing the PDF in browser. please find the attached screenshot.

Finally the above snippet which fixed the problem

Comment: header('Content-type:Application/pdf'); set this and see if it works

Comment: instead of downloading the write.pdf. sample.php is downloading. as well displaying the blank PDF page in browser

Comment: Are you identifying which PDF rendering library you are using with PHPExcel? Because I don't see any code for that!

Comment: PHPExcel\Shared\PDF  This

Answer (score 2):

You're writing the PDF out to a file:

```
 $objWriter->save('write.pdf');
```

this will not output anything to the browser, or trigger a download. You need to dump that out yourself aftewards, e.g.

```
 readfile('write.pdf');
```

or changing the save() call to

```
 $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: added screen shot, which explain little better

Comment: plz post your suggestion on answer.

Comment: if remove this "header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="export.pdf"');   " then application PHP file is downloading instead of PDF

Answer (score 0):

The Header Should come first before Creating the PDF: Try this:

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('c9','40');
//Create the header first before Writing PDF
header('Content-type:Application/pdf'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="export.pdf"');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
//You need to include and print to PDF the entire worksheets contained in the workbook
$objWriter->writeAllSheets();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```